# Selenium Diffrence between WebDriver, WebDriver Backed and Remote control

Tags: java, selenium, junit, export

I'm using `Selenium`, and I want export my test in `java` but there are 3 possibilities.

```
JAVA / Junit / WebDriver 
JAVA / Junit / WebDriver Backed 
JAVA / Junit / Remote Control
```

And I would like to know difference among these three possibilities.

Comment: For new projects, you should use `JAVA / Junit / WebDriver`.  Typically you will only use `WebDriver Backed` if you already have a Selenium RC regression suite in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: If you're not already using Selenium Remote Control (RC), you want to use the WebDriver option.

Longer answer: RC is the older 1.0 version of Selenium. WebDriver is the newer 2.0 version. WebDriver-Backed is a middle ground, allowing you to use the old RC API through the new WebDriver implementation.

You can switch between the options in the IDE and see for yourself the different tests that are generated.

More info in the [Selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc)